# Metro App Pin/Unpin to Start screen

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

How do I pin/unpin an application to the Windows 8 start screen using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pin secondary tiles to the start screen via [RequestCreateAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242213.aspx) (or one of its variants), but this step requires user approval.

If you mean create the main tile for an application that's listed in All apps, but perhaps the user had previously opted to remove the tile from the Start Screen, AFAIK there's no equivalent API for that, and it would occur only through the user opting to do so via the Start Screen UI.